# Sending a message using Discord.Py

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, discord, discord.py

I am currently trying to configure a `bot` that sends a message based on a timer! Everything works perfectly and all I need to do now is send a message. I'm not to sure how to go about this however as it's not in an async function. I have searched online and looked at other `stack overflow` posts to no avail so here I am. The code for the bot is as follows:

```
async def lava_loop_code(ctx):
    global lava_variable_1
    global Lava_bot_online
    channel = discord.Object(id='804695089485840394')
    print("Lava", lava_variable_1) 
    lava_variable_1 = lava_variable_1 + 1
    if lava_variable_1 == number_of_seconds:
        await.channel.send("Hello World") #This is the line
        print("Lava offline")
        lava_variable_1 = 0
        Lava_bot_online = True
        lava_timer.cancel()
```

The code is called from the following function:

```
    if message.channel.id == 709929044552187906: 
        print("message in lava_channel")
        lava_variable_1 = 0
        if Lava_bot_online == True:
            await channel.send("<Bot is online!") 
            print("Online")
            Lava_bot_online = False
        if lava_timer != None:
            lava_timer.cancel()
        lava_timer = setInterval(1, lava_loop_code)
```

What is needed from me to display `Hello World` in the channel? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line `await.channel.send("Hello World")` is giving you an error because you have a `.` between `await` and `channel`. You need to do `await channel.send("Hello World")`.

```py
async def lava_loop_code(ctx):
    global lava_variable_1
    global Lava_bot_online
    channel = discord.Object(id='804695089485840394')
    print("Lava", lava_variable_1) 
    lava_variable_1 = lava_variable_1 + 1
    if lava_variable_1 == number_of_seconds:
        await channel.send("Hello World") #This is the line
        print("Lava offline")
        lava_variable_1 = 0
        Lava_bot_online = True
        lava_timer.cancel()
```

Comment: Hi Aditya, I forget to update that! I am now getting this following error: 
```RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'lava_loop_code' was never awaited
  self.action()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback```

This was the original error! Any idea's on what this warning means and how I would go about fixing it?

Comment: @Hazza I think you can use asyncio.create_task(lava_loop_code()) to make it run. The error is telling you that you haven't awaited your loop call even though by using `async`, you're making it a coroutine.